# Attaching files stopped working octobercms email ajax form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, octobercms

The below setup has worked until it stopped and right now I'm perplexed why.
I've created a contact form with file attachment in OctoberCMS as below

```
{{ form_ajax('ContactForm::onSend', { files: 'true',  flash: 'true', 'data-request-files':true, 'data-request-validate': true }) }}
    <input type="hidden" name="handler" value='onSave'>
    <fieldset class="form">
        <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="Imię i nazwisko" required>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
        <input type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Telefon">
        <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Temat" >
        <textarea name="theMessage" placeholder="Zapytanie" required style="width: 100%; height: 140px;"></textarea>
        <input type="file" name="fileAttachment" id="fileAttachment" class="inputfile"  data-multiple-caption="wybrano {count}" /><label for="fileAttachment">wybierz plik </label><span class='attachmentName'></span>

    </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="send" data-attach-loading>Wyślij</button>
    </fieldset>

{{ form_close() }}
```

The component for sending email

```
<?php namespace Depcore\Parts\Components;
use Cms\Classes\ComponentBase;

use Mail;
use Lang;
use Flash;
use Input;
use Validator;
use ValidationException;
use Redirect;
use System\Models\File;

class ContactForm extends ComponentBase
{
    public function componentDetails()
    {
        return [
            'name'        => 'depcore.parts::lang.components.contactFormTitle',
            'description' => 'depcore.parts::lang.components.contactFormDescription'
        ];
    }

    public function defineProperties()
    {
        return [
              'emailTo' => [
                    'title' => 'depcore.parts::components.emailAddress',
                    'description' => 'depcore.parts::components.destinationEmailDescription',
                    'default' => 'zamowienia@kludi.pl',
                    'validationPattern' => "\A[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\z",
                    'ValidationMessage' => ''
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function onSend(){

        $data = post();
        $vars = [
            'name' => Input::get('name'),
            'subject' => Input::get('subject'),
            'phone' => Input::get('phone'),
            'theMessage' => Input::get('theMessage'),
            'fileAttachment' => Input::file('fileAttachment'),
        ];

        $rules = [
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email'
            ];

        $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

        if ($validator->fails())
            throw new ValidationException( $validator );
        else {

        Mail::send('depcore.parts::mail.message', $vars, function( $message )  use  ( $vars )  {

            // $message->to($this->property('emailTo'));
            $message->to('adam@depcore.pl');

            if ($vars['fileAttachment']) {
                $file = (new File())->fromPost($vars['fileAttachment']);
                $message->attach($file['path']);
            }

            $message->subject($vars['subject']);
            Flash::success('Wiadomość została wysłana.');
        });

      }
    }

}
```

From what I can tell is that the `Input::file('fileAttachemnt')` is always returning null so I think It could be a problem with the JavaScript framework (?).

This is a weird thing that got me by surprise when working with the project an now Im stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it looks like by mistake you used wrong **method**

```
 $vars = [
        'name' => Input::get('name'),
        'subject' => Input::get('subject'),
        'phone' => Input::get('phone'),
        'theMessage' => Input::get('theMessage'),
        'fileAttachment' => Input::get('fileAttachment'), <-- here
 ];
```

your code is using this

> Input::**get**('fileAttachemnt');

In Reality it should be this

> Input::**file**('fileAttachemnt');

may be you updated your code and didn't notice that ;)

### **UPDATE**

ok I guess there is some issue with **File** facade code **(new File())**
let not use that instead we can directly use file as also you are not saving that file so,

can you replace your code and check it once

```
$file = (new File())->fromPost($vars['fileAttachment']);
$message->attach($file['path']);
```

> **TO**

```
$file = $vars['fileAttachment'];
$pathToFile = $file->getPathname();
$fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$mime = $file->getMimeType()
$message->attach($pathToFile, ['as' => $fileName, 'mime' => $mime]);
```

then check it, it should work.

### MORE UPDATE

I added modified version of ajax framework (added js snippet), code is taken from October cms official git repo, and just removed some part of it so it can override existing code without conflicts.

I would suggest, take this code and **create ajax-fw-override.js file** then include file on your page or just duplicate layout and add it at very bottom, any how it should come after October default ajax **{% framework %}**, so it can override its **Request**.

**This is not good solution** but considering that you can't update your cms version we can use this. (also by making duplicate layout we make sure it won't affect anywhere else).

I tested it on your site using console and it worked. so just check it out and let me know.

---

```js
+ function($) {
  "use strict";

  var Request = function(element, handler, options) {
    var $el = this.$el = $(element);
    this.options = options || {};

    /*
     * Validate handler name
     */
    if (handler === undefined) {
      throw new Error('The request handler name is not specified.')
    }

    if (!handler.match(/^(?:\w+\:{2})?on*/)) {
      throw new Error('Invalid handler name. The correct handler name format is: "onEvent".')
    }

    /*
     * Prepare the options and execute the request
     */
    var $form = options.form ? $(options.form) : $el.closest('form'),
      $triggerEl = !!$form.length ? $form : $el,
      context = {
        handler: handler,
        options: options
      }

    $el.trigger('ajaxSetup', [context])
    var _event = jQuery.Event('oc.beforeRequest')
    $triggerEl.trigger(_event, context)
    if (_event.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    var loading = options.loading !== undefined ? options.loading : null,
      isRedirect = options.redirect !== undefined && options.redirect.length,
      useFlash = options.flash !== undefined,
      useFiles = options.files !== undefined

    if (useFiles && typeof FormData === 'undefined') {
      console.warn('This browser does not support file uploads via FormData')
      useFiles = false
    }

    if ($.type(loading) == 'string') {
      loading = $(loading)
    }

    /*
     * Request headers
     */
    var requestHeaders = {
      'X-OCTOBER-REQUEST-HANDLER': handler,
      'X-OCTOBER-REQUEST-PARTIALS': this.extractPartials(options.update)
    }

    if (useFlash) {
      requestHeaders['X-OCTOBER-REQUEST-FLASH'] = 1
    }

    /*
     * Request data
     */
    var requestData,
      inputName,
      data = {}

    $.each($el.parents('[data-request-data]').toArray().reverse(), function extendRequest() {
      $.extend(data, paramToObj('data-request-data', $(this).data('request-data')))
    })

    if ($el.is(':input') && !$form.length) {
      inputName = $el.attr('name')
      if (inputName !== undefined && options.data[inputName] === undefined) {
        options.data[inputName] = $el.val()
      }
    }

    if (options.data !== undefined && !$.isEmptyObject(options.data)) {
      $.extend(data, options.data)
    }

    if (useFiles) {
      requestData = new FormData($form.length ? $form.get(0) : null)

      if ($el.is(':file') && inputName) {
        $.each($el.prop('files'), function() {
          requestData.append(inputName, this)
        })

        delete data[inputName]
      }

      $.each(data, function(key) {
        requestData.append(key, this)
      })
    } else {
      requestData = [$form.serialize(), $.param(data)].filter(Boolean).join('&')
    }

    /*
     * Request options
     */
    var requestOptions = {
      url: window.location.href,
      crossDomain: false,
      context: context,
      headers: requestHeaders,
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        /*
         * Halt here if beforeUpdate() or data-request-before-update returns false
         */
        if (this.options.beforeUpdate.apply(this, [data, textStatus, jqXHR]) === false) return
        if (options.evalBeforeUpdate && eval('(function($el, context, data, textStatus, jqXHR) {' + options.evalBeforeUpdate + '}.call($el.get(0), $el, context, data, textStatus, jqXHR))') === false) return

        /*
         * Trigger 'ajaxBeforeUpdate' on the form, halt if event.preventDefault() is called
         */
        var _event = jQuery.Event('ajaxBeforeUpdate')
        $triggerEl.trigger(_event, [context, data, textStatus, jqXHR])
        if (_event.isDefaultPrevented()) return

        if (useFlash && data['X_OCTOBER_FLASH_MESSAGES']) {
          $.each(data['X_OCTOBER_FLASH_MESSAGES'], function(type, message) {
            requestOptions.handleFlashMessage(message, type)
          })
        }

        /*
         * Proceed with the update process
         */
        var updatePromise = requestOptions.handleUpdateResponse(data, textStatus, jqXHR)

        updatePromise.done(function() {
          $triggerEl.trigger('ajaxSuccess', [context, data, textStatus, jqXHR])
          options.evalSuccess && eval('(function($el, context, data, textStatus, jqXHR) {' + options.evalSuccess + '}.call($el.get(0), $el, context, data, textStatus, jqXHR))')
        })

        return updatePromise
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var errorMsg,
          updatePromise = $.Deferred()

        if ((window.ocUnloading !== undefined && window.ocUnloading) || errorThrown == 'abort')
          return

        /*
         * Disable redirects
         */
        isRedirect = false
        options.redirect = null

        /*
         * Error 406 is a "smart error" that returns response object that is
         * processed in the same fashion as a successful response.
         */
        if (jqXHR.status == 406 && jqXHR.responseJSON) {
          errorMsg = jqXHR.responseJSON['X_OCTOBER_ERROR_MESSAGE']
          updatePromise = requestOptions.handleUpdateResponse(jqXHR.responseJSON, textStatus, jqXHR)
        }
        /*
         * Standard error with standard response text
         */
        else {
          errorMsg = jqXHR.responseText ? jqXHR.responseText : jqXHR.statusText
          updatePromise.resolve()
        }

        updatePromise.done(function() {
          $el.data('error-message', errorMsg)

          /*
           * Trigger 'ajaxError' on the form, halt if event.preventDefault() is called
           */
          var _event = jQuery.Event('ajaxError')
          $triggerEl.trigger(_event, [context, errorMsg, textStatus, jqXHR])
          if (_event.isDefaultPrevented()) return

          /*
           * Halt here if the data-request-error attribute returns false
           */
          if (options.evalError && eval('(function($el, context, errorMsg, textStatus, jqXHR) {' + options.evalError + '}.call($el.get(0), $el, context, errorMsg, textStatus, jqXHR))') === false)
            return

          requestOptions.handleErrorMessage(errorMsg)
        })

        return updatePromise
      },
      complete: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $triggerEl.trigger('ajaxComplete', [context, data, textStatus, jqXHR])
        options.evalComplete && eval('(function($el, context, data, textStatus, jqXHR) {' + options.evalComplete + '}.call($el.get(0), $el, context, data, textStatus, jqXHR))')
      },

      /*
       * Custom function, requests confirmation from the user
       */
      handleConfirmMessage: function(message) {
        var _event = jQuery.Event('ajaxConfirmMessage')

        _event.promise = $.Deferred()
        if ($(window).triggerHandler(_event, [message]) !== undefined) {
          _event.promise.done(function() {
            options.confirm = null
            new Request(element, handler, options)
          })
          return false
        }

        if (_event.isDefaultPrevented()) return
        if (message) return confirm(message)
      },

      /*
       * Custom function, display an error message to the user
       */
      handleErrorMessage: function(message) {
        var _event = jQuery.Event('ajaxErrorMessage')
        $(window).trigger(_event, [message])
        if (_event.isDefaultPrevented()) return
        if (message) alert(message)
      },

      /*
       * Custom function, focus fields with errors
       */
      handleValidationMessage: function(message, fields) {
        $triggerEl.trigger('ajaxValidation', [context, message, fields])

        var isFirstInvalidField = true
        $.each(fields, function focusErrorField(fieldName, fieldMessages) {
          fieldName = fieldName.replace(/\.(\w+)/g, '[$1]')

          var fieldElement = $form.find('[name="' + fieldName + '"], [name="' + fieldName + '[]"], [name$="[' + fieldName + ']"], [name$="[' + fieldName + '][]"]').filter(':enabled').first()
          if (fieldElement.length > 0) {

            var _event = jQuery.Event('ajaxInvalidField')
            $(window).trigger(_event, [fieldElement.get(0), fieldName, fieldMessages, isFirstInvalidField])

            if (isFirstInvalidField) {
              if (!_event.isDefaultPrevented()) fieldElement.focus()
              isFirstInvalidField = false
            }
          }
        })
      },

      /*
       * Custom function, display a flash message to the user
       */
      handleFlashMessage: function(message, type) {},

      /*
       * Custom function, redirect the browser to another location
       */
      handleRedirectResponse: function(url) {
        window.location.href = url
      },

      /*
       * Custom function, handle any application specific response values
       * Using a promisary object here in case injected assets need time to load
       */
      handleUpdateResponse: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        /*
         * Update partials and finish request
         */
        var updatePromise = $.Deferred().done(function() {
          for (var partial in data) {
            /*
             * If a partial has been supplied on the client side that matches the server supplied key, look up
             * it's selector and use that. If not, we assume it is an explicit selector reference.
             */
            var selector = (options.update[partial]) ? options.update[partial] : partial
            if ($.type(selector) == 'string' && selector.charAt(0) == '@') {
              $(selector.substring(1)).append(data[partial]).trigger('ajaxUpdate', [context, data, textStatus, jqXHR])
            } else if ($.type(selector) == 'string' && selector.charAt(0) == '^') {
              $(selector.substring(1)).prepend(data[partial]).trigger('ajaxUpdate', [context, data, textStatus, jqXHR])
            } else {
              $(selector).trigger('ajaxBeforeReplace')
              $(selector).html(data[partial]).trigger('ajaxUpdate', [context, data, textStatus, jqXHR])
            }
          }

          /*
           * Wait for .html() method to finish rendering from partial updates
           */
          setTimeout(function() {
            $(window)
              .trigger('ajaxUpdateComplete', [context, data, textStatus, jqXHR])
              .trigger('resize')
          }, 0)
        })

        /*
         * Handle redirect
         */
        if (data['X_OCTOBER_REDIRECT']) {
          options.redirect = data['X_OCTOBER_REDIRECT']
          isRedirect = true
        }

        if (isRedirect) {
          requestOptions.handleRedirectResponse(options.redirect)
        }

        /*
         * Handle validation
         */
        if (data['X_OCTOBER_ERROR_FIELDS']) {
          requestOptions.handleValidationMessage(data['X_OCTOBER_ERROR_MESSAGE'], data['X_OCTOBER_ERROR_FIELDS'])
        }

        /*
         * Handle asset injection
         */
        if (data['X_OCTOBER_ASSETS']) {
          assetManager.load(data['X_OCTOBER_ASSETS'], $.proxy(updatePromise.resolve, updatePromise))
        } else {
          updatePromise.resolve()
        }

        return updatePromise
      }
    }

    if (useFiles) {
      requestOptions.processData = requestOptions.contentType = false
    }

    /*
     * Allow default business logic to be called from user functions
     */
    context.success = requestOptions.success
    context.error = requestOptions.error
    context.complete = requestOptions.complete
    requestOptions = $.extend(requestOptions, options)
    requestOptions.data = requestData

    /*
     * Initiate request
     */
    if (options.confirm && !requestOptions.handleConfirmMessage(options.confirm)) {
      return
    }

    if (loading) loading.show()
    $(window).trigger('ajaxBeforeSend', [context])
    $el.trigger('ajaxPromise', [context])

    return $.ajax(requestOptions)
      .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (!isRedirect) {
          $el.trigger('ajaxFail', [context, textStatus, jqXHR])
        }
        if (loading) loading.hide()
      })
      .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (!isRedirect) {
          $el.trigger('ajaxDone', [context, data, textStatus, jqXHR])
        }
        if (loading) loading.hide()
      })
      .always(function(dataOrXhr, textStatus, xhrOrError) {
        $el.trigger('ajaxAlways', [context, dataOrXhr, textStatus, xhrOrError])
      })
  }

  Request.DEFAULTS = {
    update: {},
    type: 'POST',
    beforeUpdate: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {},
    evalBeforeUpdate: null,
    evalSuccess: null,
    evalError: null,
    evalComplete: null
  }

  /*
   * Internal function, build a string of partials and their update elements.
   */
  Request.prototype.extractPartials = function(update) {
    var result = []

    for (var partial in update)
      result.push(partial)

    return result.join('&')
  }

  // REQUEST PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // ============================

  var old = $.fn.request

  $.fn.request = function(handler, option) {
    var args = arguments

    var $this = $(this).first()
    var data = {
      evalBeforeUpdate: $this.data('request-before-update'),
      evalSuccess: $this.data('request-success'),
      evalError: $this.data('request-error'),
      evalComplete: $this.data('request-complete'),
      confirm: $this.data('request-confirm'),
      redirect: $this.data('request-redirect'),
      loading: $this.data('request-loading'),
      flash: $this.data('request-flash'),
      files: $this.data('request-files'),
      form: $this.data('request-form'),
      update: paramToObj('data-request-update', $this.data('request-update')),
      data: paramToObj('data-request-data', $this.data('request-data'))
    }
    if (!handler) handler = $this.data('request')
    var options = $.extend(true, {}, Request.DEFAULTS, data, typeof option == 'object' && option)
    return new Request($this, handler, options)
  }

  $.fn.request.Constructor = Request

  $.request = function(handler, option) {
    return $(document).request(handler, option)
  }

  // REQUEST NO CONFLICT
  // =================

  $.fn.request.noConflict = function() {
    $.fn.request = old
    return this
  }

  // REQUEST DATA-API
  // ==============

  function paramToObj(name, value) {
    if (value === undefined) value = ''
    if (typeof value == 'object') return value

    try {
      return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(eval("({" + value + "})")))
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error('Error parsing the ' + name + ' attribute value. ' + e)
    }
  }

}(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: Sh** i posted the wrong code, this is the part where I've desperately tried to use anything to get the result (I've updated the code)

Comment: updated answer please try that code and let me know.

Comment: The code results in an error Call to a function getPathname on non object, after checking the ajax call it seems that the files aren't being submitted. So I guess this is an octoberCMS ajax framework error.

Comment: can you share your network request headers and posted params. as here i used your same code and its working.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/siNd5vEk you can check it yourself on www.kludi.pl/pliki/dev  (the contact form on home page)

Comment: ohh I see may be its because your October cms version is not up to date,  i use EDGE version for testing and in git master branch has new updated code.
https://github.com/octobercms/october/blob/master/modules/system/assets/js/framework.js  it contains code for file upload but in your version its missing that code.

Comment: if you can not update cms version then let me know we need to add some manual code kind of hack ;) to correct upload. to make Content-Type:multipart/form-data;

Comment: by the way nice site :)

Comment: Thanks :) The problem with updating the core is that it broke my hack to include the laravel Searchy plugin for fuzzy search which is essential for the site so for now I've stayed away from it

Comment: added more updated block in answer please check it out may be this is final solution :)

Comment: I pasted the code it works on one form one one not so I'm currently searching for the difference between them two

Comment: hey let me know(link) where it worked and where didn't work I can provide you solution :)

Comment: Never mind - my stupid mistake, I left Input::get() instead Input::file(). Thank you for your help!

Comment: ha ha, cool nice to see its working for you I drooped one mail to you on "biuro@depcore.pl" please check it its from my email hardik.satasiya@gmail.com once check it when you get free.